# How to change time source from "Local CMOS Clock" to "0.pool.ntp.org"

Tags: windows-8, time

I have a Windows8 Pro computer that is synchronizing ONLY with the local cmos clock.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /query /source
Local CMOS Clock
```

I need to synchronize to 0.pool.ntp.org but is refusing to do it.
(my clock is behind more or less 30 seconds)

Things that I have tried:

1. Enable the time service and restart the pc.
2. Change the time server through windows control panel and restart the pc
3. Change time server using this command:
   w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:0.pool.ntp.org /syncfromflags:manual  /update /reliable:yes
4. Restart the pc

Every time I restart my pc, the clock is still synchronizing with the local cmos clock:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /query /source
Local CMOS Clock
```

and 30 seconds behind.

This is my configuration:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuración]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 5 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 1 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 360000 (Local)


[Proveedores de hora]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 604800 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: 0.pool.ntp.org (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 0 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)


C:\WINDOWS\system32>w32tm /query /status
Indicador de salto: 0(ninguna advertencia)
Capa: 1 (referencia primaria - sincronizada mediante radio reloj)
Precisión: -6 (15.625ms por tick)
Demora de raíz: 0.0000000s
Dispersión de raíz: 10.0000000s
Id. de referencia: 0x4C4F434C (nombre de origen:  "LOCL")
Última sincronización de hora correcta: 29/07/2021 04:36:50 p. m.
Origen: Local CMOS Clock
Intervalo de sondeo: 10 (1024s)


C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but as I stumbled across this I wanted to reply for others that will run into the same issue.

You probably need to allow port 123 (UDP) outbound in the windows firewall and/or in your (infrastructure) firewall.

Comment: ... and what's the link between a UDP port and a clock?

Comment: NTP is a built-on UDP, where port 123 is used for NTP server communication and NTP clients use port 1023 (for example, a desktop). In other words, clock is updated over network using port 1023 and 123 :)

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered exactly the same problem, but in Windows 10 Home.

Even if it is a bug in `w32tm` was introduced within a year, therefore it will take some time before it comes to the surface, because CMOS RTC clocks need some time for the drift to be so large to be clearly visible against other clocks e.g. in smartphones.

Answer (score 0):

If NTP sync worked perfectly before installing updates and not anymore it could be related to the issue MS introduced with adding `UtilizeSslTimeData` option when some intervals where 'laxed' to a totally unrealistic (outside of MS world) values like `UpdateInterval: 360000`.

I'm not really sure why `UtilizeSslTimeData` option is enabled by default and what it does, especially when there is no internet or any periodic SSL traffic on the box, but if you only have 1-2 authoritative NTP servers in you local network and `w32tm /query /source` suddenly shows `Local CMOS Clock` this code may help to restore the intervals to year 2003 defaults, when all computers where fast enough to sync time over NTP every 64 seconds with no issues:

```
powershell -C "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config' -Name UtilizeSslTimeData -Value 0"
powershell -C "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config' -Name UpdateInterval -Value 0x64"
powershell -C "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config' -Name MinPollInterval -Value 0x6"
powershell -C "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config' -Name MaxPollInterval -Value 0xa"

net stop w32time
w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org" /reliable:YES /syncfromflags:MANUAL
net start w32time
w32tm /config /update 
w32tm /resync
```

You may need to wait for 10-60 seconds until `w32tm /query /source` reflects the changes, if it works. No reboot needed.

Working configuration sample:

```
cmd> w32tm /query /configuration /verbose
```

[Configuration]

```
EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 5 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 1 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Local)

[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 0 (Undefined or NotUsed)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 1024 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
```

Comment: "_computers where fast enough to sync time over NTP every 64 seconds_" - the NTP implementation actually had/has a back-off factor so that as the synchronisation became more accurate the time interval between checks increased. A well synchronised clock might only check its upstream every 17 minutes or so